# Sigabrt in Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I'm basically a few inches away from my first step on creating my app, but it shows an error 'sigabrt' This also is on Swift 2, so I really don't know if sigabrt(s) on swift 1 and swift 2 have a difference, here are some screenshots to help you

[image]

[image]

Comment: EDIT: I linked my unconnected button, and there's still the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have forgotten to set up the identifier for your ViewController in the storyboard. As soon as you're loading your view controller from storyboard by identifier you need to set up it in storyboard like here:

[image]

If the problem is not connected to identifier, stack trace from the console might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lyuna! :D